# Neo4j spring data design

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am currently getting started with Neo4j and I would like to create a basic social media like app to understand more.

I am using spring data neo4j to connect my spring boot backend with neo4j.

My application is very simple and it just lets a User Follow another User.

Using Cypher queries, everything is quite straight forward. But I would like to not write any queries explicitly and use Repository to get the data I desire.

Here is my User class

```
    @Node
    public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="FOLLOWS", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private HashSet<User> followsReceived = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type="FOLLOWS", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
    private HashSet<User> followsGiven = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And this is my Follows class

```
@RelationshipProperties
public class Follow {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @TargetNode
    private User endNode;
}
```

Does this design make sense.

I am now a bit confused because for example if I want to find the Users a particular User follows, I get a recursive structure that loads almost the entire database in spite of implementing pagination.

Can someone please suggest me a cleaner design wherein getting users I follow and Users who follow me will not load the entire DB.

If possible I would like to implement this without the @Query annotation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `@RelationshipProeprties` class is not needed, nor used in your example. You would have to put it as the generic type into the `User's` relationship definition. But since you're not adding any properties to it, you *might* (*) skip it.

Regarding your main problem: Spring Data Neo4j loads everything that is reachable from a domain model perspective by default.
Having this circular dependency between `User` and `User` (which makes sense in the domain you are working) is expected to end in this scenario.
Older versions of SDN created a virtual barrier of 2 hops when fetching data, if not parameterized to load more.
In the newer versions SDN elevated the projections concept to define those barriers much more fine-grained. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces)

Given the use-case of loading a `User` and all of her/his followers, you might consider defining a projection like

```
interface UserProjection {
 String getName();
 Set<Follower> getFollowsReceived();
 Set<Follower> getFollowsGiven();
}

interface Follower {
 String getName();
 // no relationships defined here to break the circle
}
```

And use it in the repository like this:

```
interface UserRepository extends Neo4jRepository<User, Long> {
  UserProjection findByName(String name);
}
```

(written from the top of my head, please look at the linked documentation to figure out more details)

The important bit here is that you are only referring to another projection interface (`Follower`) within the "root" projection (`UserProjection`).
If you would refer to any defined entity (`@Node` annotated), SDN will fall back into the cyclic loading mechanism to find everything reachable again.

* Having a wrapper around the identifier gives you a performance advantage because Spring Data Neo4j uses this information to figure out if a relation already exists in the database. But for this you have to use it in your `Sets` instead of the direct relationship to the other `Users`.